# Is there a way to place blocks based on the contents data of a chest? (minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to create a command which allows one to do the following:
1.Store a block in a chest in a given slot.
2.Based on the specific block stored in the specific slot in the chest, place the specific block at a specific position in the over world (ideally relative to some specified position/entity).

The idea is to build slices of a structure by inserting blocks into the chest like a blueprint. Ideally this block placement would be relative to some block/entity to allow building in a variety of places. A bonus would be to fill a column of blocks at a given position by inserting more than one block into the same slot. Any idea how to create such a feature in mine-craft using commands, or if it is even possible?

Comment: I have exammined this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351255/minecraft-command-blocks-using-data-string-values-within-other-commands?rq=1 and it seems to be that such a functionality is not yet possible. However I am not certain so I will not place it as  an answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://cloudwolfyt.github.io/pages/gens/block-id.html

has a block serializer which allows "custom in" which lets u dictate the pathing from block -> thing to do which would 100% b able to do this

something like
"execute if data block ~ ~ ~ Items[{id:"$block"}] run setblock ~ ~ ~ $block"
in custom_in might work ofc you need to specify the slot